# Multivariable limit $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x_0, 1)}\frac{x}{y^2-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that this limit does not exist. I´ve already tried with polar coordinates, and by approximation with curves, and I'm running out of methods to do it. Any ideas?

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x_0, 1)}\frac{x}{y^2-1}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to apply the definition of a limit, and to show it can't apply if $x_0 \neq 0$ ?

Comment: maybe converges, but in the "infinity" sense

Comment: @Bilou06 No I haven't, I'll try now, I was going for something maybe a little simpler, but I can try.

Comment: What you mean is show that this diverges because the limit will generally be $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @Bilou06 The thing is, I don't know where 'should' it converge to apply the definition. It's kind of tricky.

Comment: @user88595 I guess that if I prove that the limit is infinite is enough... I don't know if it´s infinite or just oscilant

Comment: I'm sorry if that's not the correct term, I don't know how you say in english that a functions does not have any limit whatsoever

Comment: @LunaSage : You say it's divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x_0, 1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{y^2-1}\right)\in \mathbb R$, then, since $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x_0, 1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{y+1}\right)\in \mathbb R$, it follows that $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x_0, 1)}\left(\dfrac{1}{y-1}\right)\in \mathbb R$, but this last limit equals $\lim \limits_{y\to 1}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-y}\right)$.

Comment: you mean $y \to 1$ in the last limit right?

Comment: @LunaSage Yes, of course. Thank you.

Comment: No, thank you! I think I got it: If the limit existed then, as the first limit exists, the second one also should, but as it is infinite, is absurd? One thing though, in this case is easy, but I should make sure that the first limit does not converges to zero, because in that case I would have a $0*\infty$ situation right?

Comment: I'm sorry for my redaction, is barbaric, but it´s really been a while since i write something in English

Comment: @LunaSage You're right. But it can converge to $0$ (if $x_0=0$).That needs to be dealt with separately. I'll do it later if you can't manage.

Comment: I  did it, thank you! I approximated it by $x=m(y-1)$, and I got that the limit depends on $m$

Comment: @LunaSage Very good ^_^